# Programmatical equivalence of Remove-NetEventSession

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

[`Remove-NetEventSession`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268512.aspx) is a powershell cmdlet that removes a network event session.

It's usually used after `Stop-NetEventSession` and `Get-NetEventSession`:

```
$session = Get-NetEventSession
Stop-NetEventSession $session.Name
Remove-NetEventSession $session.Name
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result using .Net? (Not by executing a powershell script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Using the WMI API for .Net ([`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) you can manipulate the `MSFT_NetEventSession` instance.

The following example gets the running session ([there can be only one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs)), stops it if it's running and removes it:

```
var netEventSession = new ManagementClass("/root/standardcimv2:MSFT_NetEventSession").
    GetInstances().
    Cast<ManagementObject>().
    SingleOrDefault();
if (netEventSession != null)
{
    if ((byte)netEventSession["SessionStatus"] == 0)
    {
        netEventSession.InvokeMethod("Stop", null, null);
    }
    netEventSession.Delete();
}
```